# How to write inner join with sub query in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

How to make inner join with sub queries in SQL Server?

I have an `Orders` table with columns `orderId`, `OrderNumber` and another table  `Order transactions` with `orderId`, `orderstatuscode` columns and `orderstatuscode` values like 'SHI', 'PAY', 'APQ'.

In `Orders transactions` table I have multiple record with `orderid` and `orderstatuscode`.

I want result among all traction we need orders where it should have PAY transaction but not APQ transaction

Comment: You can use a `JOIN` or an `APPLY`. What about your attempt didn't work? What *was* your attempt?

Comment: Also what you're asking and what you describe you want seem like 2 very different things. What you describe you want seems like a `NOT EXISTS`; which you don't do as an `INNER JOIN`.

Comment: Make it easy, and possible to assist you: [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have provided very little information to help you with. Having said that, this could be a good starting point :

```
SELECT      *
FROM        Orders ord
INNER JOIN  OrderTransactions tra ON ord.OrderId = tra.OrderId
WHERE       tra.OrderStatusCode = 'PAY'
AND         tra.OrderId NOT IN (SELECT      OrderId
                                FROM        OrderTransactions
                                WHERE       OrderStatusCode = 'APQ')
```

You can check this here : [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/d6536/4)

Comment: The WHERE clause here has two conditions, but if OrderStatusCode = 'PAY' - it can't be 'APQ'. OP probably wants NOT EXISTS or something similar.

Comment: @jarlh I That's correct, I agree. But we don't know if an orderId has multiple matching records or not. As I mentioned, there is very little info(read sample data/minimal reproducible example) provided to work with, I only tried to provide a starting point to the OP.

Comment: @SatwikNadkarny orderId will have multiple records in OrderTansactions table

Comment: @Ramakrishna.p You can see the fiddle. This should be what you're looking for

Comment: @jarlh I know we can use `EXISTS` clause as well. But for the sake of ease for the OP, I have just kept it simpler.

Comment: Just a not, many users find the NOT IN result a bit "surprising" if the subquery returns null values.